# PHP: how to split a string with a delimiter

Tags: php, preg-split

I have this string that I would like to split.I want it to split the string starting with 1060 and retain the string but when I use preg_split(), it removes the string.

my code is this:

```
$array = preg_split("/1060[\s]*/",$str);
```

if there is any other method or function i can use, i will be very grateful.

Regards,

Comment: Give example of your strings? Are they multi-line ones? This way the viewers may give you better answer.

Comment: use explode function in PHP.

Comment: Why you dont use `string chunk_split ( string $body [, int $chunklen = 76 [, string $end = "\r\n" ]] )`?

Comment: You can put the part of the delimiter you want to preserve in a capturing group and use the flag: `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`

Comment: `preg_split('/(1060)\s*/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Comment: Do you want `1060` to be part of the captured string? Or captured as a separate string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positive lookaheads:

```
$array = preg_split("/(?=1060\s)/",$str);
```

`(?=1060\s)` is a positive lookahead - it asserts that the regex inside it (`1060\s`) can be matched, but doesn't match it. Therefore, this will match an empty string right before the match and split the text correctly.

Comment: What is a positive lookahead? What part of the regular expression provides the positive lookahead?

Comment: A positive lookahead matches if it's internal expression matches, but doesn't consume any of the characters, so it'll match an empty string at the right position and should split there.